# Render массива из props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Пишу свой поиск по массиву, хочу изначально отображать массив таким какой он есть и потом при изменении value менять само отображение массива. Не понимаю почему он не отображается в принципе, явно что-то не так делаю, подскажите пожалуйста. В Реакте новичек, поэтому любая критика очень приветствуется, заранее благодарен.

Мой компонент Search:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.listItems = this.props.items;
    }

    state = {
        value: ''
    };

    renderArr = (arr) => {

        return <ul>
            {arr.map((i, key) => {
                return <li key={key}>{i}</li>
            })}
        </ul>
    };


    filterArr = e => {

        const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

        this.listItems = this.props.items.filter(item => {
            return item.toLowerCase().includes(value);
        });

        console.log(this.listItems);

        return this.renderArr(this.listItems);

    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            value: this.search.value
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="">

                <input type="text"
                       ref={input => this.search = input}
                       onChange={this.filterArr}
                />


            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблему решил записав полученный в props массив в state, но не знаю насколько это правильно...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.listItems = this.props.items;
    }

    state = {
        value: '',
        arr: []
    };

    renderArr = (arr) => {

        return <ul>
            {arr.map((i, key) => {
                return <li key={key}>{i}</li>
            })}
        </ul>
    };


    filterArr = e => {

        const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

        this.setState({
            arr: this.props.items.filter(item => {
                return item.toLowerCase().includes(value);
            })
        })

    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            value: this.search.value
        });
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            arr: this.props.items
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="">

                <input type="text"
                       ref={input => this.search = input}
                       onChange={this.filterArr}
                />

                {this.renderArr(this.state.arr)}

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```